# Display all records from a table where ROW_NUMBER>1 in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number

I am trying to display all the records from a table where `RN > 1`

This is the code and the steps that I have followed

```
Create table #Data(id int,name Varchar(max))

Insert into #Data values
(1,'A'),
(2,'A'),
(3,'A'),
(4,'B'),
(5,'B'),
(1,'C')

Select *,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by name order by id) as rn
into #temp
from #Data

--Fetching Subsequent records
select * from #Data
where name in 
(
   Select distinct name from #temp where rn>1
)
```

Output:

```
id  name
1   A
2   A
3   A
4   B
5   B
```

Can someone suggest a better approach that will not include intermediate temp table and a Sub query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it correct you want to count how many times each `name` occurs. And select names whose count > 1. Then no need to use `row_number`. Check this query

```
select
    id, name
from (
    select
        *, cn = count(*) over (partition by name)
    from
        #Data
) t
where
    cn > 1
```

Output

```
id  name
--------
1   A
2   A
3   A
4   B
5   B
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Cte`, and get records with `rownum`

```
with cte as
(
Select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by name ) rn
from #Data)
select Id,Name from cte where rn<=1
```

Comment: Don't we need to tell the column names like with cte(id,name,rn) as

Comment: @ErayBalkanli           I have commented out at the bottom of my answer to include column names

Comment: The issue with this is that it is missing records. I need to get all the records for A and B.

Comment: @SurajChoudhary Partiiton by swapped with order by column and your rn <2 to get required output

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
select a.* from (
    Select *,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by name order by id) as rn
    from #Data
) a
WHERE a.rn>1
```

The rn is in a subquery, then the where clause on the outside filters that out.

Comment: The Expected output is the output that i have put on the question but without using a Sub query if that is possible

Comment: you could left outer join on the name/ min combination and filter out that data...but truthfully...thats technically a subquery

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full working example, much like @B House, however using a variable table instead of temp table, and you did say rn > 1

```
declare @example as table (
    exampleid int
,   name_ varchar(max)
);

insert into @example (exampleid, name_)
select 1, 'A' union all
select 2, 'A' union all
select 3, 'A' union all
select 4, 'B' union all
select 5, 'B' union all
select 1, 'C';

     ;with cte as (
        select row_number() over(partition by name_ order by exampleid) rn
             , *
          from @example
        )

        select *
          from cte
         where rn > 1
```

### output

```
rn  exampleid   name_
2   2           A
3   3           A
2   5           B
```